# pressed focused next button

Tags: java, android, button, focus

В приложении на *Android* использую 10 кнопок и фокус при нажатии на кнопку.

Если я выбираю кнопку 1, она становится в фокусе, если я выбираю кнопку 2, то уже две кнопки в фокусе. Мне нужно поочерёдно выводить кнопки в фокус, то-есть, если я выбираю кнопку 2, то у первой фокус пропадает, а у второй появляется.

Код для кнопок:

```
View.OnTouchListener list = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            view.setPressed(true);
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.bt0:
                    break;
                case R.id.bt1:
                    break;
                case R.id.bt2:
                    break;
                ...............
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Быть может вы хотите организовать свой RadioButton?
Он уже есть, и решает часть вашей задачи

Comment: Это не совсем то,у меня используются обычные Button,при выборе меняется её цвет

Comment: вы можете кастомизировать радиобаттон под любой вид, в том числе и обычных кнопок. Делать свою реализацию того, что уже есть в API не практично.

Comment: Приду домой и попробую посмотреть в android studio radiobutton,хочется минимизировать процесс с такой лёгкой задумкой,не хочется в общем загружать код из-за такой мелочи

Comment: вот [хороший пример](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/radiobutton.php)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

создайте метод в котором будете снимать фокус с требуемых кнопок

```
private void removeFocuseAllButton(){
      //например так (можно лист перебрать в цикле)
      //(или проверять, если есть фокус - снимать)
    button1.clearFocus();
    button2.clearFocus();
    button3.clearFocus();
    ...
    //10 кнопок думаю не проблема пробежать (:

   }
```

в слушателе после события вызываете этот метод, далее как у вас задумано

```
View.OnTouchListener list = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event {

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            removeFocuseAllButton();//здесь удаляем везде фокус
            view.setPressed(true);
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.bt0:
                    break;
                case R.id.bt1:
                    break;
                case R.id.bt2:
                    break;
                ...............
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```